# How to retrieve Selector properties directly from object in repo (not from object on page)

Tags: katalon-studio

Is there a way to retrieve the selector value directly from an object repository object? have tried variations on `GetProperty` and `GetAttribute` and they always return null.

Comment: Appreciate those! What's odd is that xpath doesn't appear to be returned in the instantiated object properties, which is what we're struggling with.

Comment: Have you tried the workaround found on Katalon forum?

Answer (score 0):

Once you instantiate a test object, it is possible to explore its properties:

```
TestObject to = findTestObject('Object Repository/Test Object')
println to.getProperties()
```

See [documentation](https://api-docs.katalon.com/com/kms/katalon/core/testobject/TestObject.html) for more methods on test objects.

If that doesn't work, try this workaround:

```
String json = JsonOutput.toJson(to)
println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json)
```

From [Katalon forum](https://forum.katalon.com/t/unable-to-retrieve-xpath-value-from-object-repository-object-why/84678).